# Delphi DBExpress Parent Child No corresponding master record found

Tags: delphi, datasnap, dbexpress

I am using DBExpress to connect to MySQL. I have a master detail relationship between two tables. I am providing the parent table via DatasetProvider. On the client side I have 2 clientdatasets. One of them accesses the provider, has all the parent field + the nested dataset field of the child. The second clientdataset Dataset field property is set to the nested dataset field of the parent.

Now when I add a new record in the child dataset, it gives me an error "No corresponding master record found."

Don't know why.

Nirav

Answer (score 1):

There is a big bug in clientdataset and the tdatasetfields (nesteddataset) when you do link.
This happens in XE and XE2
Rules:
   If you want nested dataset with one provider, you must have the same column name for link       table Period.