# DataSnap Master/Detail Relationship - Post raises exception with message "No corresponding master record found"

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, datasnap

A duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10297744/delphi-dbexpress-parent-child-no-corresponding-master-record-found), but since the answer there wasn't accepted I thought maybe there's a workaround.
I have two `TSQLTable` components on my `datasnap` server which are in a master/detail relationship, and one `TDataSetProvider` linked to the master table. On my client application, there are two `TClientDataSet` components, of which one is nested in the other naturally. When I try to post a *new* record to the detail dataset, even before calling `ApplyUpdates()`, the mentioned exception is raised. Is this really a bug in XE2? How to work around it?

Here's the diagram SSMS generated for the tables:
[image]

Comment: Can you provide the field lists of the two tables?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume the master detail relation is by CenterID -> ID. This does not work as expected.

The Midas internals require to use the same field name in both datasets to establish a master detail relationship. Giving your layout it tries to establish a relation using the ID field in both tables.

To resolve this rename the ID field in Centers to CenterID.